# Python object instantiation inside a class (strange behavior)

Tags: python

I don't understand why this happens:

When I use the `add_promo()` function to add a `promo` object directly to `self.spl` (using its `self.spl.add(promo)` function) each Day object gets a different `StoryPromoList` object.

But if I add the `promo` through `self.cpl.add_promo(promo)` which basically just does the same thing but with an extra step, each Day object gets assigned the same `StoryPromoList` object, instead of different objects.

The `StoryPromoList` objects are created but only the last one is used for all days for some reason.

This is the `Day` class:

```
class Day():
    def __init__(self, date:date):
        self.date = date
        self.spl = StoryPromoList()
        self.fpl = FeedPromoList()
        self.cpl = CombinedPromoList(self.spl, self.fpl)
        self.weekday = self.date.weekday()      

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Day object (date='{self.date}')>"

    def add_promo(self, promo):
        self.cpl.add_promo(promo)
        # assign promo to the corresponding timeblock

    def get_all_promos(self):
        print(self.spl._id, self.date, self.cpl)
        return {'story_promos': [p for p in self.cpl.spl.list], 'feed_promos': [p for p in self.cpl.fpl.list]}
```

When I execute the `get_all_promos()` function for each day I get this output:

```
6 2021-09-27 <__main__.CombinedPromoList object at 0x00000244AADABBE0>
6 2021-09-28 <__main__.CombinedPromoList object at 0x00000244AADAB9A0>
6 2021-09-29 <__main__.CombinedPromoList object at 0x00000244AADAB730>
6 2021-09-30 <__main__.CombinedPromoList object at 0x00000244AADAB4C0>
6 2021-10-01 <__main__.CombinedPromoList object at 0x00000244AADAB250>
```

This is the `CombinedPromoList` class:

```
class CombinedPromoList():
    def __init__(self, spl=StoryPromoList(), fpl=FeedPromoList()) -> None:
        self.spl = spl
        self.fpl = fpl

    def add_promo(self, promo):
        if promo.type_name() == 'story':
            self.spl.add(promo)
        elif promo.type_name() == 'feed':
            self.fpl.add(promo)
```

And this is the `StoryPromoList` which is the same as `FeedPromoList` with minor differences:

```
class StoryPromoList():
    classes = []
    _id = 0
    def __init__(self, list=[]):
        self.id=StoryPromoList._id
        StoryPromoList._id += 1
        StoryPromoList.classes.append(self)
        self.list = list

    def add(self, storypromo:StoryPromo):
        self.list.append(storypromo)
```

Comment: The problem is you are using mutable default arguments, like `list=[]`, so that there is a single list instance shared across all of your `StoryPromoList` instances. Please see the linked duplicates.

Comment: This explains the problem in some depth: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it. My code was full of mutable default arguments. Never doing that again, lol.